# java soap web services .wsimport

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am new to webservices and I am very eager to learn more about web services.
But when I try to parse a WSDL using the `wsimport` tool from command prompt I get an error.

WSDL url: http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL

error:

> [ERROR] com.sun.istack.internal.SAXParseException2; www.webservicex.net
>
> Failed to read the WSDL document: http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL, because 1) could not find the document; /2) the document could not be read;
>   cument is not .
>
> [ERROR] failed.noservice=Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s):
>
> At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided.
>
> ```
>    Failed to parse the WSDL.
> ```

Comment: i didnt get what you mean

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you have set your proxy server.

You can set it by going to internet explorer.
Inside Internet explorer go to  settings(tools) > Internet Options > Connections > Lan Settings > Proxy Server

Give a proxy server and port number.

Proxy server and port number will vary differently from organisation to organisation.